# Images don't display on website created with GoogleAppEngineLauncher?

Tags: google-app-engine

When I view the pages locally, they show up. But, when I deploy and view, I get a 404 or just the alternate text shows up.

The site is troop-398.appspot.com.

Here is the snippet in my index.html:

```
`<img src="images/IMG_0190.jpg" alt="Bluejay Point" width="760"/>`
```

Here is my app.yaml:

```
application: troop-398
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))

- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: robots.txt
  upload: robots.txt 

- url: .*
  script: main.py

- url: /images
  static_dir: static/images
```

My directory structure is:

```
folder website
  files including index.html
  folder images
     IMG_0190.jpg
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

You got your static directory all wrong try something like this:

```
- url: /assets
  static_dir: assets
```

inside your assets folder you can create 3 other folders

```
root
  index.html
  contact.html

  -assets
       js
       img
       css
```

and then in your index.html page you can reference your static files in the following way:

```
<img src="/static/img/IMG_0190.jpg" alt="Bluejay Point" width="760"/>
```

Comment: I tried all sorts of configurations of folders and directories, but in the end, what fixed it was removing all spaces and underscores from the file names of my images.  Thank you for your help!